# Seaborn multiple barplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, grouped-bar-chart

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    class       men       woman   children
0   first   0.91468    0.667971   0.660562
1   second  0.30012    0.329380   0.882608
2   third   0.11899    0.189747   0.121259
```

How would I create a plot using seaborn that looks like this? Do I have to rearrange my data in some way?

[image]
<sub>(source: [mwaskom at stanford.edu](https://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/_images/seaborn-factorplot-7.png))</sub>

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**Tested in `python 3.12.0`, `pandas 2.1.1`, `matplotlib 3.8.0`, `seaborn 0.13.0`**

Reshape the DataFrame with [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) or [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# convert the dataframe to a long format
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars="class", var_name="sex", value_name="survival rate")
dfm
Out: 
    class       sex  survival rate
0   first       men       0.914680
1  second       men       0.300120
2   third       men       0.118990
3   first     woman       0.667971
4  second     woman       0.329380
5   third     woman       0.189747
6   first  children       0.660562
7  second  children       0.882608
8   third  children       0.121259
```

Consolidate the plot by creating a single facet with grouped bars, instead of multiple facets with single bars.

Plot with the [`figure-level`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) method [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html)

```
g = sns.catplot(x='class', y='survival rate', hue='sex', data=dfm, kind='bar', height=5, aspect=1)
```

Plot with the [`axes-level`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) method [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)

```
# the following code matches the plot produced by catplot
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = sns.barplot(x='class', y='survival rate', hue='sex', data=dfm)
ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)
```

[image]

---

#### Deprecated

`factorplot` (v0.8.1 or earlier):

```
sns.factorplot(x='class', y='survival rate', hue='sex', data=df, kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 13):

To produce the plot in the OP, I used the following code, after converting the dataframe from wide-form to long-form.

**Tested in `python 3.12.0`, `pandas 2.1.1`, `matplotlib 3.8.0`, `seaborn 0.13.0`**

Data:

```
d = {'class': ['first', 'second', 'third', 'first', 'second', 'third', 'first', 'second', 'third'], 'sex': ['men', 'men', 'men', 'woman', 'woman', 'woman', 'children', 'children', 'children'], 'survival_rate':[0.914680, 0.300120, 0.118990, 0.667971, 0.329380, 0.189747, 0.660562, 0.882608, 0.121259]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

```
g = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=df, x='sex', y='survival_rate', col='class')
```

[image]

---

#### Deprecated

```
sns.factorplot("sex", "survival_rate", col="class", data=df, kind="bar")
```

[image]